# Updating Elasticsearch record for a given id gives Error [ ]

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I am trying to update a field in ES record and it errors out.

ES JSON document

```
{
  "_index": "Barroz",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "pGcGz3gBRea5RG",
  "_version": 67,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "tid": "f90a48519ceeb9e43f21898363b59",
    "taep": "test.treat",
    "cluster": "Barroz.GuardianofDGamasTreasure",
    "state": "Failure",
    "notes": "Looks good"
  }
}
```

What I am trying:

```
elastic_client = Elasticsearch(["http://localhost:9200"])

query_body = {"_source": { "state": "Success" } }

elastic_client.update(index="Barroz", doc_type="_doc", id=pGcGz3gBRea5RG, 
body=query_body)
```

I am getting the below error:

```
    status_code, error_message, additional_info
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'x_content_parse_exception', 'Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [state].')
```

Please let me know whats the mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `update` endpoint accepts the following body, i.e. simply replace `_source` by `doc`:

```
query_body = {"doc": { "state": "Success" } }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is mentioned in ElasticSearch `7.17` [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/docs-update.html#_update_part_of_a_document) to wrap the body in the `doc` key to perform partial updates to the document.

```
{
    "doc": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3"
    }
}
```